# *** has not been declared (though it is)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, circular-dependency, googlemock

That is a part of a larger project, but looks like this files cause the problem.

**StreamImpl.hpp**

```
class StreamImpl {
...
    template <typename Type>
    StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept;
...
};

#include "StreamTemplateImpl.cpp"
```

**StreamTemplateImpl.cpp**

```
// Templates implementation needed for test purposes
#include "StreamImpl.hpp"
#include "MockStreamImpl.hpp"

using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl; // Error here

template <typename Type>
StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept
{
    return Dispatcher<MockStreamImpl>::Instance().Get()->OutOperator(out);
}
```

**MockStreamImpl.hpp**

```
#include "StreamImpl.hpp"
namespace mock {
using ::StreamImpl;
class MockStreamImpl {
   MOCK_METHOD(...); // Gmock methods
};
}  // namespace mock
```

Helper class to avoid code duplication:

**Fixture.hpp**

```
#include "MockStreamImpl.hpp"

namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

And file with test cases, which uses StreamImpl mocks:

**Tests.cpp**

```
#include "Fixture.hpp"
... // Test cases
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_unit_test(
    TEST_NAME
        test_unit
    TEST_SOURCES
        unit_test_source_file.cpp
        ${SOURCES}/file_to_test.cpp
        ${MOCKS}/fake_stream_impl.cpp // source file with fake StreamImpl functions  implementations which redirects to mocks
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        ${INCLUDES}
        ${MOCKS}
        ${UTILS}
        ${FAKE_STREAM_IMPL_TEMPLATES} 
    LIBS
        gmock
        gtest
        gtest_main
)
```

And when I try to compile this I got

```
In file included from /path/src/StreamImpl.hpp:281:0,
                 from /path/test/unit/mocks/MockStreamImpl.hpp:23,
                 from /path/test/unit/mocks/Fixture.hpp:24,
                 from /path/test/unit/unit_test_source_file.cpp:23:                                                                                                       
    /path/test/unit/mocks/fake_templates/StreamTemplateImpl.cpp:25:18: error: '::mock' has not been declared                                                     
     using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
```

All headers have guards so I'm not sure about circular dependency, but if it is, I'll be really thankful for explanation.

Also when I compile this without `Fixture.hpp` (`Fixture.hpp` content is merged into `unit_test_source_file.cpp`) all builds perfectly.

I'm really can't understand where is the problem and will be thankful for any help.

I saw a lot of related topics but neither seems contains answer for me.

Comment: `#include "StreamTemplateImpl.cpp"` bad idea. Many tools (and humans) will detect and compile this cpp file, resulting in multiple definition errors or other problems when the program is linked. Give the file some other extension and you're good to go.

Comment: @user4581301 agree, but this way I can mock templated methods. I don't see any other workaround how to do it with google mock. Ok, I see. Will rename it to .hpp

Comment: StreamImpl.hpp includes StreamTemplateImpl.cpp which includes MockStreamImpl.hpp which includes StreamImpl.hpp. Round and around we go. Multiple inclusion is prevented by header guards, but sooner or later something is expected to be defined, but isn't because its header has been started but was interrupted by another include before being fully examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an architectural problem, you are abstracting the different types of streams in a bad spot, that cannot easily be untangled. The mock interface is too tightly entwined with the code under test. You can hack around this, but you are better off stopping and thinking through exactly what you want to test.

Sort of side note:

`StreamImpl` is a bad idea.

```
StreamImpl& operator<<(T &&out) noexcept;
```

is non-standard and part of how you got into this problem. If you use the standard

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & strm,  T &&out) noexcept;
```

and turn `StreamImpl` into a child of `std::ostream` you can pass in a re-write of `MockStreamImpl` that is ALSO a child of `std::ostream` and completely hide the specialization of the stream inside the stream rather than the function writing to the stream.

Side note to the side note: Templating `operator<<` isn't a very good idea either. Most types don't have similar-enough rules to be printable by a generic function. This leads to goofy output or confused error messages when the `<<` template tries to invoke itself because it's still the best match.

What went wrong:

If we follow the includes and perform the substitutions we can see what the compiler sees:

```cpp
#include "MockStreamImpl.hpp"

namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

leads to

```cpp
#include "StreamImpl.hpp"
namespace mock {
using ::StreamImpl;
class MockStreamImpl {
   MOCK_METHOD(...); // Gmock methods
};
}  // namespace mock
namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

and then to

```cpp
class StreamImpl {
...
    template <typename Type>
    StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept;
...
};

#include "StreamTemplateImpl.cpp"

namespace mock {
using ::StreamImpl;
class MockStreamImpl {
   MOCK_METHOD(...); // Gmock methods
};
}  // namespace mock
namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

and then, yawn, to

```cpp
class StreamImpl {
...
    template <typename Type>
    StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept;
...
};

// Templates implementation needed for test purposes
#include "StreamImpl.hpp"
#include "MockStreamImpl.hpp"

using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl; // Error here

template <typename Type>
StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept
{
    return Dispatcher<MockStreamImpl>::Instance().Get()->OutOperator(out);
}
namespace mock {
using ::StreamImpl;
class MockStreamImpl {
   MOCK_METHOD(...); // Gmock methods
};
}  // namespace mock
namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

and since StreamImpl.hpp and MockStreamImpl.hpp are protected by include guards we get

```cpp
class StreamImpl {
...
    template <typename Type>
    StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept;
...
};

// Templates implementation needed for test purposes

using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl; // Error here

template <typename Type>
StreamImpl &operator<<(T &&out) noexcept
{
    return Dispatcher<MockStreamImpl>::Instance().Get()->OutOperator(out);
}
namespace mock { //because mock isn't found by the compiler until here
using ::StreamImpl;
class MockStreamImpl {
   MOCK_METHOD(...); // Gmock methods
};
}  // namespace mock
namespace fixture {
using ::mock::MockStreamImpl;
using ::utils::Dispatcher;
using ::testing::Test;

class UtStream : public Test {
   // Class for setting up mocks and common test data which is used as fixture in tests
   
    StreamImpl kDefaultStream_{};
}
}  // namespace fixture
```

where we can see that `MockStreamImpl` is required before it is defined.